# C#-style event accessors for CLI events in F#

Tags: .net, events, f#, c#-to-f#

I am exposing an event from F# to C# like this:

```
let event = new DelegateEvent<EventHandler>()
member x.Ping() = event.Trigger([| x; EventArgs.Empty |])
[<CLIEvent>]
member x.PingEvent = event.Publish
```

But I'd like some code to run whenever handlers are added or removed. I think this can be done in C# like this:

```
public event EventHandler PingEvent
{
    add 
    {
        //do something
    }
    remove
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

How do I write the above in F#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In F#, you can define events with implementations of the `IDelegateEvent<_>` interface (or the `IEvent<_>` or `IEvent<_,_>` interfaces which derive from it).  So you can do something like this:

```
let customEvent add remove =
  { new IDelegateEvent<_> with
        member this.AddHandler del = add del
        member this.RemoveHandler del = remove del }

type MyType() =
  let ev = customEvent (* your add handler *) (* your remove handler *)

  [<CLIEvent>]
  member this.myEvent = ev
```

Comment: I think the `new Event<'a>()` on the first line is unnecessary. Did you want to write just `{ new IEvent<'a> with ... }`? As it is, it creates an implementation of `IEvent` that also inherits `Event`, but the base class is not used for anything (and shouldn't be needed).

Comment: I created a quick example with .Net 7 today: https://github.com/aligneddev/fsharpToCSharpEvent

Comment: @kvb If I use this code I get compiler error
Error FS1091 The event 'ClockEvent' has a non-standard type. If this event is declared in another CLI language, you may need to access this event using the explicit add_ClockEvent and remove_ClockEvent methods for the event. If this event is declared in F#, make the type of the event an instantiation of either 'IDelegateEvent<_>' or 'IEvent<_,_>'.

Answer (score 2):

You could also wrap an event if you wanted triggering.

```
type MonitoredEvent<'a>(add, remove) =
    inherit Event<'a>() 

    let bp = base.Publish
    let p = { new IEvent<'a> with 
                member this.AddHandler del = 
                    add()
                    bp.AddHandler del
                member this.RemoveHandler del = 
                    remove()
                    bp.RemoveHandler del
                member this.Subscribe o = 
                    failwith "Not implemented"
                }

    member this.Publish = p

type Something() =
    let mutable listeners = 0
    let add() = listeners <- listeners + 1
    let remove() = listeners <- listeners - 1
    let me = new MonitoredEvent<_>(add, remove)

    member this.Ping x = me.Trigger (sprintf "%d %s" listeners x)

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member this.PingEvent = me.Publish

let computer = new Something()
computer.PingEvent.Add(printfn "%s")
computer.Ping "first"
computer.PingEvent.Add(printfn "-%s-")
computer.Ping "second"
```

output

```
1 first
2 second
-2 second-
```