# F# event with exposed add/remove functions and consumable from C#

Tags: events, f#, .net-8.0

With reference to https://stackoverflow.com/a/4964791/2323934, I am trying to use that code in .NET 8

```
let customEvent add remove =
  { new IDelegateEvent<_> with
        member this.AddHandler del = add del
        member this.RemoveHandler del = remove del }
```

```
...
    let clockEvent = customEvent (fun _ -> ()) (fun _ -> ())

    [<CLIEvent>]
    member __.ClockEvent = clockEvent
...
```

It seems to work as there are no intellisense errors. However the project raises a build error

> Error FS1091  The event 'ClockEvent' has a non-standard type. If this
> event is declared in another CLI language, you may need to access this
> event using the explicit add_ClockEvent and remove_ClockEvent methods
> for the event. If this event is declared in F#, make the type of the
> event an instantiation of either 'IDelegateEvent<*>' or 'IEvent<*,_>'.

Note that the error disappears if I remove the `[<CLIEvent>]` line, but then the event cannot be consumed in C#

[image]
How to fix this error?

Comment: It looks like your event is generic. You never define what type of delegate it should be.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin would be too much to ask for a working snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your event ends up generic. If you look closely, you'll see that while it's known that `ClockEvent` should have type `IDelegatedEvent<'a>` (because `customEvent` returns a `IDelegatedEvent`), it is *not* known what `'a` is.

This means that member `ClockEvent` is *generic* (has a type parameter `'a`), and generic events aren't allowed.

To fix, just add a type annotation *somewhere*, so that the compiler can infer the type. Could be here:

```
member __.ClockEvent : IDelegateEvent<System.EventHandler> = clockEvent
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or could be here:

```
let clockEvent = customEvent (fun (_ : System.EventHandler) -> ()) (fun _ -> ())
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or even on `customEvent`'s signature:

```
let customEvent (add : System.EventHandler -> _) remove =
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Doesn't matter where exactly, the compiler just needs to know the type you want *somehow*. Right now you're not telling it.

(obviously replace `System.EventHandler` with the actual delegate you want there; I used `EventHandler` just for example, because it's the most basic one)

Answer (score 1):

For the `IDelegateEvent<_>` to work with the CLI events, it expects to invoke a `Handler<_>` delegate.

In other words, `IDelegateEvent<_>` is too generic and should instead be `IDelegateEvent<Handler<_>>`.

This change is enough to fix the problem and let  type inference handle the rest.

```ml
let customEvent add remove =
  { new IDelegateEvent<Handler<_>> with
        member this.AddHandler del = add del
        member this.RemoveHandler del = remove del }
```